# Excel window does not fill the entire workspace

Tags: microsoft-excel, window, workspace

I have only one excel file open and it is maximized, however, I can see a good portion of the workspace behind it on the right side…

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

how can I reclaim that screen real estate?

This also happens if the "big" excel window is not maximized but it's stretched to the ends of the screen.

Comment: I believe you are in 'tiled" mode on this "older" version of excel. I can't remember how to get to the title bar when it is under the ribbon (because if you could you would see the thingy to maximize). Maybe go to "view" in the ribbon.

Comment: oh, maybe if you un-maximize excel, then the scroll bars will appear that will allow you to scroll around in the excel "work area" so you can get to the maximize buttons on that particular sheet...

Comment: @gns100 I tried both of those and it didn't work. I could tile the window and then maximize it without solving the issue. Also closing the Excel program did not solve it, it only got solved when I restarted the machine. Thanks anyway for taking the time to reply and try to help!